# How to calculate difference in hours (decimal) between two dates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, decimal

I have to calculate the difference in hours (decimal type) between two dates in SQL Server 2008.

I couldn't find any useful technique to convert datetime to decimal with 'CONVERT' on MSDN.

Can anybody help me with that?

UPDATE:
To be clear, I need the fractional part as well (thus decimal type). So from 9:00 to 10:30 it should return me 1.5.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

`DATEDIFF(hour, start_date, end_date)` will give you the number of hour boundaries crossed between `start_date` and `end_date`.

If you need the number of fractional hours, you can use `DATEDIFF` at a higher resolution and divide the result:

```
DATEDIFF(second, start_date, end_date) / 3600.0
```

The documentation for `DATEDIFF` is available on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28SQL.105%29.aspx

Comment: Great idea. BTW--the same functions exist in .Net too so this is useful in VB.Net or C#.

Comment: Why not DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_date, end_date) / 60.0

Comment: @irfandar The `datepart` passed to `DATEDIFF` will control the resolution of the output. For example, if `start_date` and `end_date` differed by 59 seconds, then `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_date, end_date) / 60.0` would return 0, but `DATEDIFF(second, start_date, end_date) / 3600.0` would return 0.0163888 (59/3600).

Comment: this solution is just returning the integer number. if the time difference is only 15 minutes then the hour is returning 0. I think the following solution is more realistic.

Comment: @AsadNaeem The solution (using `DATEDIFF` at a higher resolution than hour) works. For example, `SELECT DATEDIFF(second, DATEADD(minute, -15, GETUTCDATE()), GETUTCDATE()) / 3600.0` returns 0.250000.

Comment: @PhilRoss Agreed more accurate

Comment: @PhilRoss Agreed if we convert it to float like that Cast(DATEDIFF(second, DATEADD(minute, 0, @Dt1), @Dt2)as Float) / 3600.0 then more accurate while the adding of all times

Comment: Also be careful if you're doing this in a GROUP BY, as you cannot put two aggregates inside another aggregate to get the MAX() dates for example. In my case, I had to use CTE

Answer (score 17):

Just subtract the two datetime values and multiply by 24:

```
  Select Cast((@DateTime2 - @DateTime1) as Float) * 24.0
```

a test script might be:

```
  Declare @Dt1 dateTime Set @Dt1 = '12 Jan 2009 11:34:12'
  Declare @Dt2 dateTime Set @Dt2 = getdate()

  Select Cast((@Dt2 - @Dt1) as Float) * 24.0
```

This works because all datetimes are stored internally as a pair of integers, the first integer is the number of days since 1 Jan 1900, and the second integer (representing the time) is the number of (**1**) ***ticks*** since Midnight.  (For SmallDatetimes the time portion integer is the number of minutes since midnight). Any arithmetic done on the values uses the time portion as a fraction of a day.    6am = 0.25, noon = 0.5, etc...   See [MSDN link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277(SQL.80).aspx) for more details.

So Cast((@Dt2 - @Dt1) as Float) gives you total days between two datetimes.  Multiply by 24 to convert to hours.  If you need total minutes, Multiple by Minutes per day (24 * 60 = 1440) instead of 24...

**NOTE 1**: This is not the same as a dotNet or javaScript tick - this tick is about 3.33 milliseconds.

Comment: Nice trick. SQL should include a named constant. I felt dirty when typing 24, but I guess that's what I get for not being Ronald McDonald.

Answer (score 9):

DATEDIFF but note it returns an integer so if you need fractions of hours use something like this:-

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(ss, startDate, endDate) AS decimal(precision, scale)) / 3600
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Postgres I had issues with DATEDIFF, but had success with this:

```
  DATE_PART('day',(delivery_time)::timestamp - (placed_time)::timestamp) * 24 + 
  DATE_PART('hour',(delivery_time)::timestamp - (placed_time)::timestamp) +
  DATE_PART('minute',(delivery_time)::timestamp - (placed_time)::timestamp) / 60
```

which  gave me an output like "14.3"

Answer (score 1):

```
DATEDIFF(minute,startdate,enddate)/60.0)
```

Or use this for 2 decimal places:

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(minute,startdate,enddate)/60.0 as decimal(18,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269%28SQL.80%29.aspx) function.

> DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

Where you code might look like this:

DATEDIFF ( hh , startdate , enddate )

Comment: The 'hh' interval won't do what he wants. He needs a smaller interval so he can compute fractional hours.

Answer (score -1):

```
Declare @date1 datetime
Declare @date2 datetime

Set @date1 = '11/20/2009 11:00:00 AM'
Set @date2 = '11/20/2009 12:00:00 PM'

Select Cast(DateDiff(hh, @date1, @date2) as decimal(3,2)) as HoursApart
```

Result = 1.00

Comment: DateDiff() returns an int. You could cast to decimal, but it's already truncated the mantissa.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, firstDate, secondDate)
FROM tableName
WHERE ...
```

Comment: DateDiff() returns an int. You could cast to decimal, but it's already truncated the mantissa.