# Calculation about more than 24 hours in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to create a column that will store hours bigger than 24. For example `'25:00:00'`, `'129:23:12'`, etc).

That column will be used to perform calculations between `datetime` intervals: 'time'.

I was trying

```
SELECT  CAST((CAST(CAST(RIGHT('107:37', 6) as datetime) AS FLOAT))/(207.160) AS DATETIME)
```

if it

below `'23:59'` instead of `'107:37'` working fine.

`'107:37'` give error:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in
>   an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: That's silly.  If you want to calculate time or date intervals, then why not just use the datetime type, and time and date functions?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to store just the number of seconds? Converting to hours and minutes is simple arithmetic.

Comment: No, it would be simpler to store the number as a datetime, and use functions like datediff().  For example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770594/how-to-calculate-difference-in-hours-decimal-between-two-dates-in-sql-server

Comment: To convert hours and minutes to datetime use `select dateadd (hour, 107, dateadd(minute, 37, 0))`. 0 gives 1-1-1900; you might want to change it to some other date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the value as a datetime data type. You can do mathematical calculations on datetime data types, such as +, -, SUM, MIN, MAX, etc, and you can use DateDiff and DateAdd as well. The only tricky bit you're going to have is in displaying the value as HHHH:mm:ss. You can do that easily enough, though:

```
DECLARE @datetime DATETIME
SET @datetime = 4.2
SELECT CAST((FLOOR(CAST(@datetime AS FLOAT)) * 24) + DatePart(Hour, @datetime) AS VARCHAR) + 
    ':' + CAST(DatePart(Minute, @datetime) AS VARCHAR)
    + ':' + CAST(DatePart(Second, @datetime) AS VARCHAR)
```