# difference in days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am very new at this.
I need in a seperate column in this query to have the difference in days
between t.1start and t1.finish.

Thanks ,Louie

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TOWN) AS 'row', 
T1.Surname,
T1.Forename,
T1.Town,
T1.Description,
T1.Sex,
T1.DOB,
T1.start,
T1.finish,
FROM dbo.viewServiceContractFull T1 
WHERE
T1.finish>='2013/01/01'
and 
T1.finish<='2013/01/31'
```

How do I now get only certain towns to come up in query?

Comment: DATEDIFF ( day , startdate , enddate ), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770594/how-to-calculate-difference-in-hours-decimal-between-two-dates-in-sql-server

Comment: What database system? SQL Server? Oracle? Also, do `start` and `finish` contain just dates, or might they contain a time component also? If the latter, should the difference take account of these or ignore them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TOWN) AS 'row', 
T1.Surname,
T1.Forename,
T1.Town,
T1.Description,
T1.Sex,
T1.DOB,
T1.start,
T1.finish, cast(DATEDIFF(DAY,T1.start,T1.finish) as varchar) as difference
FROM dbo.viewServiceContractFull T1 
WHERE
T1.finish>='2013/01/01'
and 
T1.finish<='2013/01/31'
```

Additionally have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: How do I now get only 2 towns to come up in query?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (MyUnits, '2010-01-22 15:29:55.090', '2010-01-22 15:30:09.153')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function to determine the intervall between  two dates, you can use the [CAST/CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to transform your string dates into real dates if needed, like:

```
CAST('2010-01-22 15:29:55.090' AS DATETIME)
```

The CONVERT function enables you to choose the format of the date.

Comment: sql server and they containg just dates ie. '2013/03/30' How to use datediff in my query above??