# SQL find out the hours between 2 date time column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

Is it possible to give condition if 2 of my time column has difference in more than 15 hour.

Given `colTime1`, `colTime2` in `table`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time between colTime1 and colTime 2 is difference for over 15 hours
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770594/how-to-calculate-difference-in-hours-decimal-between-two-dates-in-sql-server here is similar question about sql server

Comment: You can use the TIMESTAMPDIFF

See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579946/only-show-hours-in-mysql-datediff

Comment: TIMEDIFF and DATEDIFF are a MySQL time difference functions, see if there's the same functions in your language.

Comment: What is the data type of `colTime1` and `colTime2`?

Comment: what calTime1 and calTime2 holds? date or hours only?

Comment: both column hold DateTime
thanks guys, mysql did have a function for DATEDIFF.
just found it on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: make sure your date format also include time , other wise this return difference in days

```
DATEDIFF(hour, date1 ,date2);
```

for days

```
DATEDIFF(date1 ,date2);
```