# Calculating difference in dates using sql?

Tags: java, sql-server, date, jdbc

I want to calculate the difference between the current date and a date stored in a database which I have stored as a variable. Here are my problems:

1. I am dealing with java.util.Date for the currDate and java.sql.Date for the stored date - call it startDate. As I store startDate into my program as a variable it truncates the hours, minutes, and seconds of the DATE object. I assume this is a problem with converting.
2. I am not sure how the UTC effects my calculation??

I am very new to coding, any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate difference in hours (decimal) between two dates in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770594/how-to-calculate-difference-in-hours-decimal-between-two-dates-in-sql-server)

Comment: If you are working in SQL you can use `convert(date,currDate,110)` and `convert(date,startDate,110)` to get them both into the same date format, as long as they are both valid date strings

Comment: @msaggar Start by reading the doc to understand the data types of both Java and SQL. A java.util.Date is a date plus time-of-day while a java.sql.Date is a date-only without any time-of-day.

Answer (score 1):

[`ResultSet#getDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate-int-) returns only the date part. If you want to get the full timestamp including hours, minutes, etc, you should user [`ResultSet#getTimestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp-int-) instead.