# Time Difference between two dates in Minutes and hours like 1hr 20Min in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I need to calculate job time between two dates i.e. I am having table with name job and in that table i am having jobStartDate and JobCompleteDate as Datetime fields now i need to get time duration between those 2 dates i.e.

**AS Mentioned by J.D my question is not duplicate 
I Verified this answer:** [SQL time difference between two dates result in hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss)

**My Query**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,jobStartDate,JobCompleteDate) FROM tbl_Jobs
```

**My result**

```
1
```

**Expected Output**

```
1:20 Hr
```

Comment: What if difference > 24 hours. Can you give example output?

Comment: this is the of similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249778/datediff-to-output-hours-and-minutes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL time difference between two dates result in hh:mm:ss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577898/sql-time-difference-between-two-dates-result-in-hhmmss)

Comment: Mr. J.D first read question carefully...... and then mark it as duplicate. @J-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @sd DATETIME = '2015-11-03 10:45:35.747'
DECLARE @ed DATETIME = '2015-11-03 15:20:35.747'

SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(ss, @sd, @ed) / 3600 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ':' +
       CAST((DATEDIFF(ss, @sd, @ed) -  3600 * (DATEDIFF(ss, @sd, @ed) / 3600)) / 60 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Hr'
```

Output:

```
4:35 Hr
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CAST`

```
Select CAST((@jobEndDate-@jobStartDate) as time(0)) '[hh:mm:ss]'
```

Comment: This will not work for period greater then 24 hours.

Comment: First `DateDiff` can be used and then `Convert`

Comment: I need only hours and minutes.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770594/how-to-calculate-difference-in-hours-decimal-between-two-dates-in-sql-server